# How do I include whitespaces in an input taken from a user? (c++)

Tags: c++, whitespace

i wanted to let a user input a string which has whitespaces.but my compiler seems to only take the character and does not include the whitespace.
I have entered the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
     char str[100];
     cout<<"Enter the value";
     cin>>str;
     cout<<"Value is :";cout<<str;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this related to `cppcheck`? Please don't add tags unless they're relevant (and mentioned in the question).

Comment: will check on that one. thank you @NutCracker

Comment: Thank you for the info @Sme Programmer dude . I wasnt aware of that.

Comment: @NutCracker That would do the same thing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `std::string` instead of `char` array along with [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
     std::string str;
     std::cout << "Enter the value: ";
     std::getline(std::cin, str);
     std::cout << std::endl << "Value is :" << str;
     return 0;
}
```

`std::getline` takes new line character `\n` as a default delimiter. Therefore, `str` variable will have whitespaces included.

Comment: @RanjulRamachandran glad i could help. Please accept and upvote if you liked the answer.

Comment: I will ,as soon as the 10 mins passes ,cheers!

Comment: also @NutCracker is it against the rules of this website to ask question related to tech but not related to coding?

Comment: im a newbie to this site

Comment: @RanjulRamachandran it is against the rules. StackOverflow is only for coding question. But you can find another community on StackExchange that is responsible for tech questions. Here you have all [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: The real answer here is the getline part. Switching to string is a good suggestion but not the actual fix

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ..hmm..to be noted..thank you.